# Does Ash walk away from the starting pokemon in the anime?

Tags: pokemon

I've not seen the show, but I used to play the video games. In Pokemon Go there is a secret way to get Pikachu by walking away from the starting Pokemon. People on the internet say Ash did so in the anime. Is that true? If not, how can this be explained with anime's events?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In episode 1 of the anime, Ash overslept and was too late to get Bulbasaur, Charmander or Squirtle. Professor Oak then gives him Pikachu.

Comment: Ash still got Pikachu this way, but he didn't necessarily 'refuse' Bulbasaur, Charmander, and Squirtle in the sense that literally walking away from them does. This was buy mistake